# Multiple google maps on a single page -- can only load one at a time

Tags: javascript, html, r

I'm very new to HTML and Javascript (less than a week of experience) and am stuck in the following situation. I created 6 google map visualizations using the googleVis package for R (simple stuff--just markers on a map). I've extracted the Javascript out of the googleVis objects in R and have included them in a simple site that contains 6 divs for each of the 6 different maps.

Each Javascript file includes a function to create a JSON object, a function to draw the map, and a function to display the map:

```
//define JSON    
function gvisDataWest ()
        {
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          var datajson =
        [
         [
             33.5313,
          -112.1774,
        "<p>2005-2009 Poverty Rate: 40.7%</p> <p>2000 Poverty Rate: 34.3%</p> <p>Significant difference: 0.0 points </p>" 
        ],
        ... many rows of data ...
    ];
    data.addColumn('number','Latitude');
    data.addColumn('number','Longitude');
    data.addColumn('string','tip');
    data.addRows(datajson);
    return(data);
    }

//draw chart
function drawChartWest() {
  var data = gvisDataWest();
  var options = {};
options["showTip"] = true;
options["enableScrollWheel"] = true;
options["width"] =    400;

     var chart = new google.visualization.Map(
       document.getElementById('West')
     );
     chart.draw(data,options);
}

//display chart
function displayChartWest()
{
  google.load("visualization", "1", { packages:["map"] }); 
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartWest);
}
```

Each javascript file includes functions and data for a different region of the country (e.g. there would be definitions for gvisDataMidwest(), givsDataSouthEast(), etc.).

Here's roughly what my HTML looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta content="text/xml; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script src="../povscripts/map1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../povscripts/map2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../povscripts/map3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../povscripts/map4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../povscripts/map5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../povscripts/map6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      ...a bunch of divs, headers, <p>'s, etc...
      ...then six divs like this, each with an appropriate id:
        <div class="anncdiv"> 
            <div class="bannertitle">
                <p class="btxt">West</p>
            </div>
            <div class="anncdivIn" id="West">
            <script type="text/javascript"> displayChartWest() </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="anncdiv"> 
        <div class="bannertitle">
            <p class="btxt">Midwest</p>
        </div>
        <div class="anncdivIn" id="Midwest">
        <script type="text/javascript"> displayChartMidwest() </script>
        </div>
    </div>
```

THE PROBLEM: With the way I've currently cobbled this site together, if there are two dsplayChart****() functions being called anywhere on the site (as in this example, with displayChartWest() and displayChartMidwest()) all divs appear blank. But, if I were to just include one of these function calls, then the map displays fine in the appropriate div. Somehow calling two or more of these functions results in a conflict, though I just don't know why. Your help is GREATLY appreciated. Cheers, AR

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to wait until the DOM is loaded before firing up your charts. Without using a library like jQuery, you could do it using the body onload event:

```
<body onload="displayCharts()">
...page source...
<script type="text/javascript">
    function displayCharts() {
        displayChartWest();
        displayChartMidwest();
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I thought it might be something like this, but when I tried using onload in the body tag, or window.onload, or even including jQuery and using something like $(document).ready(), I was met with the same result.

Comment: I tried loading this on another machine and was able to get three of the maps to load, but adding a fourth map (or fourth call to a displayChart****() function) broke the site. My limited understanding has me thinking about ways to order the loading of the maps, but I'm not sure where to turn...

Comment: Hmm, how about putting each map in a separate `iframe`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages:["map"] }); 
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartWest);
```

try this instead:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages:["map"],callback: drawChartWest});
```